# Is it possible to reuse created jmeter test plan for another test environment?

Tags: jmeter, wiki, reusability

I have recorded a jmeter script for wiki page. That record was done in one of our test environment. That script is working fine and now i want to perform same load test for another test environment(Both environments are same, only urls are different).Is it possible to reuse?How can i do it?

I have added HTTP Request default element at the begging of test plan creation. Now recorded script consist of many HTTP Request element. Each request element contains Server IP of test instance.

Answer (score 1):

1. Extract IPs and other env-specific data to `.properties` file:
   http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#options
2. Read them in your JMeter with JMeter built-in function `${__P(someName)}` as you see fit
3. Run your generic JMeter test with env-specific config data in `.properties` file

Answer (score 1):

Yes. It is possible to run the same test in multiple environments. It all depends on how you design your test plan.

This site has exact details you are looking for. 
http://www.testautomationguru.com/jmeter-manage-test-plan/

Comment: I have used HTTP request element and entered the server name there.So now sever name is not in other HTTP Requests.When i uses that script for another test instance i have changed that server name which is define in HTTP Request default element into new server name.Those test instances are wikis.So there are different ids(Parameters) recorded in each request.when we use recorded script for another instance those ids are different in another.It is possible to do this?

Comment: @Udani, I see. It is possible. Usually the IDs in the HTTP requests are coming the previous HTTP response. You need to use `Regular Expression Extractor` to grab those & use it in subsequent requests. Basically you should not have any hardcoded values in your test plan to make it work for all the environments.